# PHP function to generate Unique n digits random numbers

Tags: php

I need a php function that create n digit random number that is unique; here is what i tried

```
//Function to generate random code
 function getUniqueCode($length)
 {
   for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
   if($i==0)
    $code = str_pad(mt_rand(1, 9), 1, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
   else
    $code .=    str_pad(mt_rand(0, 9), 1, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
   }
   return $code;
 }
```

If I use this function to generate 9 digits number eg. 129534546, is there any possibility of generating numbers that are not unique, If YES what should I change so that I can be sure that the possibility of repeating a number is zero

Comment: Without checking all previous numbers generated you can never be 100% sure a number will not repeat.

Comment: In your title it says: to generate unique numbers and now you ask how to create not unique numbers ?

Comment: I think php `rand` function is your solution. Isn't it?

Comment: Rizier123 the question is not to create duplicate numbers but to avoid the chance of getting them.

Answer (score 0):

There are always possibilities, be it smaller or larger.

You can check from previously stored numbers, if you saving them in database or something.

OR

The second option would be, append random numbers to a file called `numbers.txt`, seprated by `,` and when generating a new number, check if that matches within the file, if matches, generate another number.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quickly response,I thought about it but the concern was the processing speed, Think of a situation where I want to generate 600,000 numbers

Comment: It is good if its a one time task, if not you need to include characters like `a-z` to your generator function to minimize the possibilities of duplicates if you are not checking for duplicates inside generator function.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a chance to you might end up getting duplicate number, not sure when but it may, so change code to this :

```
function getUniqueCode($length)
{
   for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
   if($i==0)
      $code = str_pad(mt_rand(1, 9), 1, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
   else
      $code .=    str_pad(mt_rand(0, 9), 1, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return $code;
 }


 $tempArray = array();  


 $tempCode = getUniqueCode(9); //here 9 is number digit you want randon number you want

 if (!in_array($tempCode, $tempArray)) {
     $tempArray[] = $tempCode;
 }
```